# Consuming Custom Request Methods with iOS5

Tags: iphone, rest, ios5, nsurlconnection, asihttprequest

My original question regarding [Consuming Custom Request Methods with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742273/consuming-custom-request-methods) seems to have garnered very little attention -- *I have converted it to an Android specific question*

So, quite simply, with iOS5 development, is it possible to consume custom request methods?

If so, how.

The "standard" set of request methods, as per [RFC-2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) are:

- GET
- PUT
- POST
- DELETE
- TRACE
- CONNECT

I would like to add another, called `SEARCH`.  On the API, using PHP or Java, this is easy to implement in PHP.  The consumption of this new request method is proving to be a challenge for an iOS developer.

Does anyone have any references to working examples or frameworks that will support a custom request method, such as `SEARCH`, or `FOOBAR`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASIHTTPRequest allows it: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

Check out the 'PUT requests and custom POSTs' section.

```
[request setRequestMethod:@"SOME_REQUEST_METHOD"];
```