# jersey http client custom request method

Tags: java, rest, jersey, httpurlconnection

With the following code, using `jersey`:

```
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-apache-client4</artifactId>
    <version>1.13-b01</version>
```

I have issues using custom request methods, like FOOBAR, PATCH, SEARCH, etc.  Those which do not exist in `httpUrlConnection`.

```
 DefaultClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
 config.getProperties().put(URLConnectionClientHandler.PROPERTY_HTTP_URL_CONNECTION_SET_METHOD_WORKAROUND, true);

 Client c = Client.create(config);
 Form f = new Form();
 f.add("id", "foobar");

 WebResource r = c.resource("http://127.0.0.1/foo");
 String methodName = "foobar";
 String response = r.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).header("USER-AGENT", "my-java-sdk /1.1").method(methodName.toUpperCase(), String.class, f);
```

The result is the following exception:

```
 com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ProtocolException: Invalid HTTP method: FOOBAR
```

I have tried various ways to try and resolve this, without success.

- http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-639 has been implemented above in the `config.getProperties()` line.  Still receiving the error
- when i switch to the apache http client, i receive 411 errors from the server receiving the requests for all non-GET and non-PUT requests.

Long story short, I want to implement similar functionality as is available in via Java:

- [Consuming Custom Request Methods with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742273/consuming-custom-request-methods-with-android)
- [Consuming Custom Request Methods with iOS5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076883/consuming-custom-request-methods-with-ios5)

Thank you in advance for your feedback

Comment: could you please provide some server-side code where you recieve this request.

Comment: The request is never received server side due to the Invalid HTTP method exception

Comment: @sdolgy can you post the full stack. This is going to be (most likely) an error inside Jersey.

Answer (score 5):

With Jersey 2.x `Client`, we would set the property

- [`HttpUrlConnectorProvider.SET_METHOD_WORKAROUND`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/client/HttpUrlConnectorProvider.html#SET_METHOD_WORKAROUND)

to `true`

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
client.property(HttpUrlConnectorProvider.SET_METHOD_WORKAROUND, true);
String response = client.target(url).request().method("PATCH", entity, String.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for this up-to-date answer for Jersey 2.x! Solved it for me!

Answer (score 3):

It is not a bug, it is a feature. :)

but seriously.
HttpUrlConnection do not allow you use custom HTTP methods because:

> // This restriction will prevent people from using this class to
>
> // experiment w/ new HTTP methods using java.

So you cannot use other methods than (in java 6):  "GET", "POST", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "PUT", "DELETE", "TRACE"

Jersey provides a workaround and it uses reflection to omit this checking:

```
DefaultClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
config.getProperties().put(URLConnectionClientHandler.PROPERTY_HTTP_URL_CONNECTION
     _SET_METHOD_WORKAROUND, true);
Client c = Client.create(config);
WebResource r = c.resource("http://google.com");
String reponse = r.method("FOOBAR", String.class);
```